# Xamarin with Parse : The type ParseClient exists in both Parse.Android and Parse.iOS

Tags: xamarin, parse-platform

I am currently working on a cross-platform app with Xamarin. I am trying to use the NuGet package [Parse.Xamarin.SDK by averbin](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Parse.Xamarin.SDK/) but when I use its class ParseClient, I get this error :

```
The type 'ParseClient' exists in both 'Parse.Android' and 'Parse.iOS'
```

I never got this kind of error before. I guess its stands for a class name conflict in the DLLs but I don't know. I searched on Google but wasn't able to find a fix for this particular error. Tell me if you need more information about the structure of the solution.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: take a look at this post! https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/57982/using-parse-in-a-pcl-or-net-class-library

Comment: Thanks ! So I understand there would be no way to do it with a PCL libray ?

Comment: You could use some form of dependency injection which would allow you to call platform specific code from the PCL. Some inversion of control library, like TinyiOC [1] can help here, or if it is a Xamarin Forms solution you can use a Dependency Service [2]. [1] https://www.nuget.org/packages/TinyIoC/ [2] https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/dependency-service/